# iOS not rendering z-index properly

Tags: css, ios, safari, css-position, z-index

I have a navbar and a footer.
They are both `fixed` positioned, and both have `z-index` of `1`.

The inner div should go above them both.
It has a `fixed` position, width and height of `100vw` and `100vh` respectively,
and it's `z-index` is `2`.

Works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.
Still, for some reason Safari presents the navbar and footer above the DIV.
Why? Why Safari is the new Internet Explorer? XD

Any idea on how to solve this?

**Chrome:** (correct)

[image: chrome]

**iOS:** (buggy)

[image: iOS]

e.g.

```html
<html>
<style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
    }
    nav, footer, .overlay {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    nav, footer {
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    nav {
        top: 0;
    }
    footer {
        bottom: 0;
    }
    .overlay {
        z-index: 2;
        background-color: lightsalmon;
        height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <nav>NAV</nav>
        <div>
            <div class="overlay">
                DIV
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer>FOOTER</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The CSS code is missing.

Comment: @lukas.j thought it was quite obvious. edited the code snippet with minimal css.

Comment: Minimal CSS is not enough.

Comment: Please could you check your code because it is not legal HTML. Why is the nav element not in the body? Why is the footer also outside the body?

Comment: @AHaworth you're right. Edited with proper full minimal example.

Comment: I have just run the snippet on Safari IOS and it is acting as I would expect, that is all I see is the salmon coloured div. If I make that opacity 0 the nav and footer are there in the right places. IOS 15. What system are you running Safari on?